# Rtrim in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm using below query

```
select rtrim(ename,substr(ename,2,10))||'->'||ename from emp order by ename;
```

to get below output

```
A->ALLEN
A->AMITH
B->BlAKE
S->SMITH ...... etc
```

but i am getting output like

```
 ->ALLEN
A->AMITH
B->BlAKE
S->SMITH
```

Any suggetions please, am i missing any thing? . Why the letter "A" in first line was missing.

Comment: Please provide sample data from your emp table.

Comment: SUBSTR 2, 10 skips the first character, and RTRIM deletes the string returned by substr, why not just do SUBSTR(1, 1) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use

```
select SUBSTR(ename,1,1))||'->'||ename from emp order by ename;
```

It will return the first letter of each name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ename,1,1) + '->' + ename FROM SAMPLE ORDER BY ename;
```

I have tried the above mentioned Query in SQL Server and its working fine.